# Classpath error on Linux system, works if directory accessed from Windows

Tags: java, cross-platform, classpath

I am building a parser in Java using JFlex and JavaCUP. I copied all the necessary jar files across from my Windows development box to a Linux box, and couldn't get it to work. The command

```
java -cp jflex.jar:java-cup-11a.jar:myparser.jar main.Parser
```

gave me "Error: could not find or load main class main.Parser."

I checked the jar files: myparser.jar definitely contains main/Parser.class, and there isn't one anywhere else. Then I tried changing the order of the jar files in the classpath:

```
java -cp myparser.jar:jflex.jar:java-cup-11a.jar main.Parser
```

This time, it gave me a different error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java_cup/runtime/Scanner
```

Finally I used Samba to make the Linux directory accessible from the Windows box, and typed this:

```
java -cp jflex.jar;java-cup-11a.jar;myparser.jar main.Parser
```

This is the same as the first one except with ";" as separators instead of ":". It worked as expected, with no errors.

I thought that it might be a versioning issue ("write once, run anywhere... maybe"). When I do "java -version" my Windows machine says this:

```
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

My Linux box says this:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

So I find it hard to believe it's a versioning issue.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Windows uses `;` as a classpath separator. Everyone else uses `:`. Kind of like Windows uses ``\`` as a directory separator, and everyone else uses `/`. Windows is "special". Of further note, the dynamic classloader on Windows will perform an exhaustive search for native libraries. Everyone else will fail if the native library isn't before the jar that uses it. This is because Windows does dynamic linking "special" too.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's exactly why I changed the ":" to ";" when I issued the command in Windows. What has this to do with the problem?

Comment: *This is the same as the first one except with ";" as separators instead of ":". It worked as expected, with no errors.* I am wondering the same thing. I suspect the issue is "the dynamic classloader on Windows will perform an exhaustive search for native libraries." But without more actual detail about the problem and the code I can only speculate.

Comment: Can you explain why ""the dynamic classloader on Windows will perform an exhaustive search for native libraries" might produce the behaviour I observed? And in particular why having a jar file at the end of the classpath rather than the beginning would mean that the Linux classloader was unable to find a class within it?

Comment: java cup ships with two jar files. When you use the generated parser, then the *runtime.jar needs to be on the classpath. please add it, when you lauch your program on linux. if this should work, your JRE on windows seems to load the jar from anywhere else. maybe from jre/lib/ext?

Comment: The version I have is a single jar file (java-cup-11a.jar) but it contains a directory called "runtime". I haven't used the new version of CUP as it is vastly different to the good ol' version I'm used to.

Comment: That is why moving jars around causes "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again" on Linux and not on Windows. I have run into that one. It's because of the Windows dynamic linker.

Comment: Can someone please explain in words of one syllable or less why everyone thinks the Windows dynamic linker should make such a difference?